# does angularjs have an init interface for $routeProvider so i can do some same thing for each route

Tags: angularjs

now i start an angularjs(version:1.0.8) app like this:

```
angular.module('cms', ['angularFileUpload','ui.bootstrap']).
  config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider', function($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
    //$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    $routeProvider.
        when('/foo',{templateUrl: 'partials/foo/index.html',resolve:{nav:function(){
          renderNav();
        }}}).
        .when('/bar',{templateUrl: 'partials/bar/index.html',resolve:{nav:function(){
          renderNav();
        }}})
  }]);
```

and each time i change a route,i want to invoke the function renderNav(),so how can i do it with $routeProvider?

Comment: The way you have used it in resolve, does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the run of your application, you can listen to successfull route changes:

```
angular.module('cms').run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        // call renderNav() which could be in a factory that you inject
    });

}]);
```

You could also put the same code into a directive that you would put in your views' html where you will display the navigation.